# How to fetch a selected users image from parse in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2

I have the list of usernames of Parse in an array. 
I want to fetch the images of those selected users. 
I can fetch the image of current user as :

```
if let userPicture = PFUser.currentUser()?["profilePic"] as? PFFile {
        userPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                self.profileImage.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
            }
        }
    }
```

I have the list of usernames in the array `namesArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
// Create the PFUser query
var query = PFUser.query()

// Constrain the query to the users contained in the username array
query.whereKey("username", containedIn: namesArray)

// Find the matching users asynchronously
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (error == nil) {
        // Fetch the images of the users
        if let userArray = objects as? [PFUser] {
            for user in userArray {
                if let userPicture = user["profilePic"] as? PFFile {
                    userPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if (error == nil) {
                            // Do something with the image data
                        } else {
                            // Error handling
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        println("query error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo!)")
    }
}
```

Additionally, it may be useful to know that you cannot use `includeKey` on a PFFile. PFFile is an explicit reference to an object in the Parse data store rather than a pointer,  so `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` must be used for each user's profile picture.

Comment: I am unable to load it in table view as the error says `ArrayIndex out of range`

Comment: Sounds like this question has been answered and you are getting all of the images correctly in the array, but now you have an error elsewhere in your table view code. You should ask this in another question and include the relevant table view code. Questions on StackOverflow should be limited to a specific topic.